# Javascript library forge does not work in Internet Explorer IE8

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

I use javascript library forge for decrypting AES encrypted data. 
It works good in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer 9+. But it does not work in Internet Explorer 8. It raises error: 'forge' is undefined.
Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Have you attempted to contact Digital Bazaar? Perhaps this actually belongs on the issues page of their github: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues

Comment: I found the reason. The library uses javascript array map function which is not supported in IE8. So I just replaced in several places "map" to custom function and now I can use forge library in IE8.